# Meaning of "Error in contr.treatment(n = 0L) : not enough degrees of freedom to define contrasts" when adding fixed effects to nlme?

Tags: r, logistic, lme4-nlme, degrees-of-freedom

We are attempting to model and compare logistic growth over time for 6 different treatments using `nlme`. So far, we have successfully added random effects of individuals. However, when we try to add any combination or number of fixed effects of treatments we get "`Error in contr.treatment(n = 0L) : not enough degrees of freedom to define contrasts`". We get the same error when adding fixed effects to a model containing any combination or number of random effects. Below is a sample of our data and the code that is producing the error. In our full data set each treatment has 12 individuals, measured at 12 time steps, the sample contains measurements of one individual per treatment.
Searching the error on google only revealed a few hits that I wasn't able to gain any clarity from.

```
pacman::p_load(
  tidyverse,
  nlme)
df <- structure(list(Individual = c("SO_BF_05_MF_G", "SO_BF_05_MF_G", "SO_BF_05_MF_G", "SO_BF_05_MF_G", "SO_BF_05_MF_G", "SO_BF_05_MF_G", "SO_BF_05_MF_G", "SO_BF_05_MF_G", "SO_BF_05_MF_G", "SO_BF_05_MF_G", "SO_BF_05_MF_G", "PP_BF_05_MF_D", "PP_BF_05_MF_D", "PP_BF_05_MF_D", "PP_BF_05_MF_D", "PP_BF_05_MF_D", "PP_BF_05_MF_D", "PP_BF_05_MF_D", "PP_BF_05_MF_D", "PP_BF_05_MF_D", "PP_BF_05_MF_D", "PP_BF_05_MF_D", "PP_BF_05_MF_D", "BN_BF_02_MF_A", "BN_BF_02_MF_A", "BN_BF_02_MF_A", "BN_BF_02_MF_A", "BN_BF_02_MF_A", "BN_BF_02_MF_A", "BN_BF_02_MF_A", "BN_BF_02_MF_A", "BN_BF_02_MF_A", "BN_BF_02_MF_A", "BN_BF_02_MF_A", "BN_BF_02_MF_A", "TD_BF_02_MF_H", "TD_BF_02_MF_H", "TD_BF_02_MF_H", "TD_BF_02_MF_H", "TD_BF_02_MF_H", "TD_BF_02_MF_H", "TD_BF_02_MF_H", "TD_BF_02_MF_H", "TD_BF_02_MF_H", "TD_BF_02_MF_H", "TD_BF_02_MF_H", "TD_BF_02_MF_H", "E6_BF_13_MF_L", "E6_BF_13_MF_L", "E6_BF_13_MF_L", "E6_BF_13_MF_L", "E6_BF_13_MF_L", "E6_BF_13_MF_L", "E6_BF_13_MF_L", "E6_BF_13_MF_L", "E6_BF_13_MF_L", "E6_BF_13_MF_L", "E6_BF_13_MF_L", "E6_BF_13_MF_L", "PO_BF_08_MF_L", "PO_BF_08_MF_L", "PO_BF_08_MF_L", "PO_BF_08_MF_L", "PO_BF_08_MF_L", "PO_BF_08_MF_L", "PO_BF_08_MF_L", "PO_BF_08_MF_L", "PO_BF_08_MF_L", "PO_BF_08_MF_L", "PO_BF_08_MF_L", "PO_BF_08_MF_L"), Treatment = c("O2", "O2", "O2", "O2", "O2", "O2", "O2", "O2", "O2", "O2", "O2", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PV", "PV", "PV", "PV", "PV", "PV", "PV", "PV", 
"PV", "PV", "PV", "PV", "S1", "S1", "S1", "S1", "S1", "S1", "S1", 
"S1", "S1", "S1", "S1", "S1", "S2", "S2", "S2", "S2", "S2", "S2", 
"S2", "S2", "S2", "S2", "S2", "S2", "SO", "SO", "SO", "SO", "SO", 
"SO", "SO", "SO", "SO", "SO", "SO", "SO"), Time.days = c(0, 
5, 12, 19, 26, 40, 47, 58, 65, 72, 99, 0, 5, 12, 19, 26, 33, 
40, 47, 58, 65, 72, 99, 0, 5, 12, 19, 26, 33, 40, 47, 58, 65, 
72, 99, 0, 5, 12, 19, 26, 33, 40, 47, 58, 65, 72, 99, 0, 5, 12, 
19, 26, 33, 40, 47, 58, 65, 72, 99, 0, 5, 12, 19, 26, 33, 40, 
47, 58, 65, 72, 99), Size = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0004444, 
0.256, 0.423, 2.511, 51.08, 55.935, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.058, 0.149, 
1.711, 2.396, 14.747, 39.905, 51.462, 71.469, 0, 0, 1.111e-05, 
0, 1.094, 8.351, 15.96, 18.982, 52.926, 67.767, 70.759, 74.131, 
0, 0, 0.028, 0.971, 0.625, 2.302, 6.67, 15.891, 19.676, 51.914, 
72.486, 33.264, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.078, 0.271, 0.638, 2.165, 24.953, 
39.935, 56.932, 64.002, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.271, 0.042, 0.621, 0.338, 
18.682, 59.92, 0)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -71L))
# get start values
df_nls <- nls(Size ~ SSlogis(Time.days, Asymp, xmid, scal), data = df)
# make growth model
growth.model = function(Time.days, Asymp, xmid, scal){Asymp/(1 + exp(-(Time.days - xmid)/scal))}
# nlme with fixed effect (f) of treatment on Asymptote (A), random effect of individual on asymptote
## x is nls data, y is all data
nlme_fA <- function(x,y) {
  nlme_start <- summary(x)$parameters
  Asymp_st <- nlme_start[,"Estimate"][1]
  xmid_st <- nlme_start[,"Estimate"][2]
  scal_st <- nlme_start[,"Estimate"][3]
  start_param <- c(Asymp_st, xmid_st, scal_st)
  nlme(Size ~ growth.model(Time.days, Asymp, xmid, scal), fixed = list(Asymp ~ Treatment, xmid + scal ~ 1), random = Asymp ~ 1|Individual, data = y, start = start_param)
}

df_fA <- nlme_fA(df_nls, df)
```

I have tried:

- various combinations of individual and multiple fixed effects and random effects
- adding duplicates of the data with slight variation to see if the issue was number of replicates
- using grouped data frames `df_grp_Trt_code <- groupedData(Size ~ Time.days|Treatment/Individual, data = df)`
- using self start function `SSlogis` for nlme `nlme(Size ~ SSlogis(Time.days, Asymp, xmid, scal), fixed = list(Asymp ~ Treatment, xmid + scal ~ 1), random = Asymp ~ 1|Individual, data = y)`
- various combinations of the above attempts

All gave the same error

Is the error a result of too few replicates?

If so, is there a way for us to compare logistic growth between treatments in `nlme` while taking into account random effects?

If it isn't a result of too few replicates, what does the error mean and how can we solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you did not define Treatment as a factor.

Note: I removed your last entry since I assume it was an error

`df2 <- df[-71,]`

Define Treatment as a factor

`df2$Treatment <- as.factor(df2$Treatment)`

Create groupedData

`df2G <- groupedData(Size ~ Time.days | Individual, data = df2)`

Visualize

`plot(df2G)`

Fit logistic to each Individual

`fitL <- nlsList(Size ~ SSlogis(Time.days, Asym, xmid, scal), data = df2G)`

Fit NLME

`fnm1 <- nlme(fitL, random = pdDiag(Asym + xmid + scal ~ 1))`

Extract estimate for fixed effects

`fxf <- fixef(fnm1)`

Update model incorporating the effect of treatment

`fnm2 <- update(fnm1, fixed = Asym + xmid + scal ~ Treatment,
               start = c(fxf[1], rep(0, 5),
                         fxf[2], rep(0, 5),
                         fxf[3], rep(0, 5)))`

Test effect of each treatment

`anova(fnm2)`

Check model assumptions

`plot(fnm2)`

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: that helps A LOT! this has pretty much entirely cleared things up